# Conexão Remota Mysql 5.6 e Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mysql, servidor

Tenho uma Droplet na DigitalOcean com Mysql 5.6 no Ubuntu 15.10.
Normalmente para conexão remota altero o arquivo `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` no parâmetro `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`.

Acontece que nesta versão o arquivo `my.cnf` vem apenas com os `includes` abaixo:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Não encontrei onde alterar o `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

Já atribuí as permissões ao usuário.

Na versão `5.6` do `mysql` o `path` de arquivo de configuração mudou?

Comment: Estas diretivas apontam que nestes folders há arquivos de configuração (.cnf) para serem lidos. Provavelmente o arquivo que você procura está em `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.

Comment: @mrlew realmente este é o `path` do arquivo. Alterei o parâmetro e conseguir a conexão remota.